# Ionic app crashes in iPhone 5 but not on the emulator

Tags: ios, debugging, cordova, ionic-framework, ubertesters

I'm testing my app with iPhone5 and suddenly with my new build , facebook login stopped working. (I'm using `$cordovaOauth.facebook`). It works in the iOS emulator by connecting to the same public web API.

My question is, how do you normally check the error logs when it crashes on the actual phone?

I'm using [ubertesters](http://ubertesters.com/) to create my `.ipa` file. They have an SDK as well, but I couldn't get it running in my Ionic app. it gives the following error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined`

I have setup the script as they say in the [article](http://ubertesters.com/sdk-cordova/).

```
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/ubertesters.js"></script>
```

I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to debug a situation like this (it works in the iOS emulator).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `type="text/javascript"` to each line of your script. See the example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ubertesters.js"></script>
```

This should solve the issue with Ubertesters SDK integration.